# Make a div of equal 5 divs in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to make a row of having 5 divs in a column width of 4 in bootstrep.

So the code be -

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
      <!-- Main Content -->
      <!-- Weather -->
      <div class="element">
        <div class="header_text">
          Weather
        </div>
        <div class="element_body description_text">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">sss</div>
            <div class="col-md-2">sss</div>
            <div class="col-md-2">sss</div>
            <div class="col-md-2">sss</div>
            <div class="col-md-2">sss</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Weather -->
      <!-- End Main Content -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I get a output like-
[image: Output I get]

But problem is done when I change the width of the page. It becomes vertical ins ted of remaining horizontal, like it-
[image: Output 2]

But I don't want it to be changed orientation in any time. So, I want it to be horizontal every time what if the width of the page is changed or not.

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: You only use the `lg` and `md` column sizing classes, e.g. `col-md-2`. You'll need at least column classes for the smallest, `xs`, layout. Try changing the `col-md-2` to `col-xs-2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**JSFIddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/).

**Problem:**

You are not giving the `sm` and `xs` size for it take the default behavior of `div` i.e. `display: block;`.

**Solution:**

So change `md` to `xs`.

```
<!-- Content -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
                <!-- Main Content -->
                    <!-- Weather -->
                    <div class="element">
                        <div class="header_text">
                            Weather
                        </div>
                        <div class="element_body description_text">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-2">sss</div>
                                <div class="col-xs-2">sss</div>
                                <div class="col-xs-2">sss</div>
                                <div class="col-xs-2">sss</div>
                                <div class="col-xs-2">sss</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Weather -->
                <!-- End Main Content -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- End Content -->
```